# jQuery caches elements selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using this code to:

```
$('.something').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
}
```

And for some reason, if I modify the data-id using the inspector, jQuery still sees the id that was there in the beginning. However, I tried the same thing using JS and it does see the changes. This makes me wondering if jQuery caches in some way the elements selected and uses them instead of the actual DOM.

Can someone please explain what happens and how jQuery does the event binding in the background?

Later edit: I want to specify that I'm talking about the "data-" attribute that I put in the HTML, not about the '.data()' provided by jQuery. Not sure if it's the same thing.

Comment: jQuery stores `data()` in an object in memory, so it depends how you're changing the value as to whether jQuery will see the change. Could you please show the code you used to amend the value

Comment: There was no code, I just changed the data-id value from the inspector provided by Chrome. I assume that changes made by jQuery on the data attribute are seen by jQuery, as it would modify the data object you mentioned in it's internal memory?

Comment: That's correct. jQuery builds the in-memory object on first use. Any `data-*` attribute values in the DOM are then effectively orphans (in jQuery terms) when you access anything via the `data()` method. As such, you need to use `data()` as both a getter and setter to keep the data in sync.

Comment: I see. Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jQuery caches elements selected?

No. But the data managed by [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is stored in an object cache maintained by jQuery, keyed by a unique identifier jQuery adds to the element (so it can look up the data). `data` is only *initialized* from `data-*` attributes, it is **not** an accessor for them. It's both more and less than that.

---

If you're interested, you can see that as an "expando" property on the element instance, it'll start with "jquery" and have a long number attached to it (currently; it's undocumented — **for good reason** — so this may change):

```js
var foo = $("#foo");
console.log(foo.data("info")); // hi there
console.log("Expando name: " + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo[0]).find(name => name.startsWith("jQuery")));
```

```html
<div id="foo" data-info="hi there"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, just for my understanding, when jQuery does the first selection, if it find any HTML data-* attribute, it stores it in the internal '.data()' provided by jQuery?

L.E: And from there it uses only the internal `data`?

Comment: @AlexandruBanu: Exactly. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for details. In addition to reading all the `data-*` attributes, it also guesses whether it should parse them (as numbers, as JSON) and does so if it thinks it should.